# (Wait doesn't work) Selenium Java <a> Element not interactable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Yes, already tried with all kind of waits.

I have to click on the big "Dress" block on this site: http://automationpractice.com/index.php

I CAN get the /a> and the /li> elements with Xpath, but none of them are ever "clickable" or "visible"

The following does work but I need a more "use like" solution

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title=\"Dresses\"]")));
```

Again, already tried with waiting until clickable and visible, but it just timeout after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there are two elements that match your locator. Since you are using `.findElement` (singular), it returns the first one which happens to be the one that is hidden and stays hidden unless you hover the first nav item, "Women".

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Keep the same locator, use `.findElements` (plural) and click the second element.

   ```
   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@title='Dresses']")).get(1).click();
                                                         ^ gets the second element, the first is index 0.
   ```
2. Modify your locator to find the element you want uniquely.

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#block_top_menu > ul > li > a[title='Dresses']"))).click();
   ```

I prefer the second because you can add a wait and also because it's a CSS selector. CSS selectors are more compatible, more flexible, easier to read (simpler syntax), etc.

---

Additional note: The way to avoid this issue is to always check your locators in the browser. I use Chrome because I find it to be the easiest to use and most powerful. You can open the devtools using F12. Press ESC if the Console isn't shown. In the console you can test XPaths using `$x()`, e.g. `$x("//a[@title='Dresses']")` returns 2 elements. You can test CSS selectors using `$$()`, e.g. `$$("#block_top_menu > ul > li > a[title='Dresses']")` returns only one element.

Comment: I tried both of these approaches on the site and they both work.